# How to view log of errors shown upon shutdown

Tags: shutdown, 20.04

I get 2 error messages shown very briefly when shutting down my hp notebook with 20.04 running on it. Is it safe to ignore them or should I have a look what it's about? If so where would I look?

Answer (score 7):

There is no "shutdown.log" similar to `/var/log/boot.log` in the system, probably because the "root" filesystem will be unmounted by the time the last message is displayed on the screen.

However, some shutdown messages are logged into the "journal" (not in the same format as displayed on the screen of course) and can be viewed like this:

```
journalctl -b-1 | grep systemd
```

Here, the `-b-1` option is for the previous journal to the current system boot. If you want to see information about not the last shutdown, but the one previous to that, you can use:

```
journalctl -b-2 | grep systemd
```

and so on.

To see information about system boot and shutdown times, you can use:

```
last reboot | head
```

---

As another solution to your problem look at the following answer:
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115622/330980